# Notice: Undefined variable: post in C:\wamp\www\moderna\wp-content\themes\moderna\inc\shortcodes.php on line 48

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

```
function portfolio_shortcode($atts, $content = null){
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'type' => 'post',
    ), $atts ) );

     $q = new WP_Query(
        array('posts_per_page' => 5, 'post_type' => 'portfolio')
        );              

    $list = '<div class="row">
                <section id="projects">
                    <ul id="thumbs" class="portfolio">';
    while($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post();
        $idd = get_the_ID();

        $portfolio_large = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'portfolio-large' );
        $portfolio_thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'portfolio-image' );

        $list .= '

                    <!-- Item Project and Filter Name -->
                <li class="col-lg-3 design" data-id="id-0" data-type="web">
                <div class="item-thumbs">
                <!-- Fancybox - Gallery Enabled - Title - Full Image -->
                <a class="hover-wrap fancybox" data-fancybox-group="gallery" title="'.get_the_title().'" href="'.$portfolio_large[0].'">
                <span class="overlay-img"></span>
                <span class="overlay-img-thumb font-icon-plus"></span>
                </a>
                <img src="'.$portfolio_thumb[0].'" alt="'.get_the_title().'" />

                </div>
                </li>

        ';  

    endwhile;
    $list.= '</ul></section></div>';
    wp_reset_query();
    return $list;
}
add_shortcode('portfolio', 'portfolio_shortcode');
```

Comment: `$post->ID` -> `$idd->ID` ?

Comment: Is that last line really line 48?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Questions featuring a problem squashed into the title, and no other explanatory information in the body of the question, tend to get closed.

Comment: There is only 41 lines of code in your post yet the problem is on line 48...You need to show us the code around line 48...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not including the post global before trying to use it. The lines causing an issue are:

```
$portfolio_large = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'portfolio-large' );
$portfolio_thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'portfolio-image' );
```

There are two solutions to this particular error.

1)

Add `global $post;` to the top of your function. E.g.

```
function portfolio_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
    global $post;
    ...
```

2)

You're already getting the ID with `$idd = get_the_ID();`. Use that instead of `$post->ID`. E.g.

```
$portfolio_large = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $idd ), 'portfolio-large' );
$portfolio_thumb = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $idd ), 'portfolio-image' );
```

There is also a third alternative which I'm mentioning at the end because it doesn't help you if you run into similar problems in the future. `get_post_thumbnail_id()` will work on the current post in the loop. As such you don't need to pass in any ID.

Comment: How do you know that OP even defined `$post` anywhere?!

Comment: The code is specific to WordPress. `$post` is already defined globally and not something the user needs to do themself.

Comment: Hi Nathan Dawson, Thank you very much.